# Why does docker node inspect not give an IP address that I can connect to?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I run `docker node inspect self` the IP address it provides are actually not reachable from either inside or outside a container environment.

Is there any reason why that is?  The reason I am asking is because the `dockerswarm_sd_configs` for prometheus returns that address by default.  I mean a workaround would be to change the `__address__` label it with the value of `hostname` but why would such a workaround be needed?

Actually even the hostname value does not work within the prometheus container since in my case my device host name is registered via mDNS rather than a normal DNS entry so it does not resolve internally.