# How do I get the boot time for a node given the instance information from dockerswarm_sd_config

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to get the up time from node exporter but I want to have it driven by the nodes provided by dockerswarm_sd

```yaml
- job_name: dockernodes
  scrape_interval: 5s
  dockerswarm_sd_configs:
  - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    role: nodes
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_node_hostname]
    target_label: nodename
  - source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_node_role]
    target_label: role
  - source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_node_id]
    target_label: instance
```

I got to this point

```
(up{job="dockernodes"} * on (nodename) group_right node_uname_info)
  * on (instance)  node_boot_time_seconds
```

but it ends up being zero.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the choice of operators

```
(up{job="dockernodes"} + on (nodename) group_right node_uname_info)
  * on (instance) node_boot_time_seconds
```

```
up{job="dockernodes"}
```

I expected the value to be `0` because there's no actual metric due to [Why does docker node inspect not give an IP address that I can connect to?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146885/why-does-docker-node-inspect-not-give-an-ip-address-that-i-can-connect-to)

The `node_uname_info` better return a value in my case `1`

The last one `node_boot_time_seconds` would get the final value I would need in which case I just multiply with `1`.

I can then aggregate as needed with `avg` e.g.

```
avg((up{job="dockernodes"} + on (nodename) group_right node_uname_info)
  * on (instance)  node_boot_time_seconds)
```

Answer (score -1):

You pretty much have it! Some small edits to make it cleaner and also account for boot time.

```
(time() - node_boot_time_seconds) * on(instance) group_left(nodename, role) up{job="dockernodes"}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions!